# Mongo template aggregation returns no raw or mapped result after driver change

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongo template aggregation method that has match unwind match group and project .
It was working fine in spring data mongo 2.2.5.Release with java driver 3.11.2 but after upgrade to 3.3.5 and java driver 4.4.2 it failed with bsoninvalidoperationexception
Readobjectid can only be called when the current bson type is object_id and not document
I addded @id notation in the inner document class UE this error was gone but it is not returning any value in mapped or raw result

Error

```
   readObjectId can only be called when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID, not when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT.; nested exception is org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readObjectId can only be called when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID, not when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT.
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: readObjectId can only be called when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID, not when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT.; nested exception is org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readObjectId can only be called when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID, not when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT.
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2929)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:562)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doAggregate(MongoTemplate.java:2171)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doAggregate(MongoTemplate.java:2140)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:2134)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:2026)
```

Document 1

```
    @Document(collection = "abc")
    public class AU implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1025499515231580477L;
    
        @Id
        @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdJsonSerializer.class)
        @JsonDeserialize(using = ObjectIdJsonDeserializer.class)
        public ObjectId id;
    
        private String applicationUserId;
    
        private String applicationId;
    
        private String lastName;
    
        private String firstName;
    
        private String middleName;
    
        private String email;
    
    
        private String title;
    
        private String userType;
    
        private String lastUpdateBy;
    
        private Date lastUpdateDate;
    
        private Date createdTime;
    
        private Date deletedTime;
    
        private boolean active;
    
        
        private String city;
        
        private String country;
        
    
        private List<UE> uE = new ArrayList<UE>();
        }
```

Inner Document

```
    public class UE implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
        public ObjectId eId;
    
        private String eName;
    
        private Date lastRecertDate;
    
        private String lastRecertBy;
    
        private Date createdTime;
    
        private String createdBy;
    
        private boolean revoked;
    
        private Date revokedTime;
    }
```

I tried using @BsonProperty("id") and @BsonId but it didnot work

Edit::

I was going through the aggregation query . I ran in debug mode and found the aggregation same in both the jar version however in the aggregation of 3.3.5 spring data mongo I found .addToSet("uE").as("ue") with group as the culprit and giving the above error on removing it it works,

```
Aggregation aggregation =
        newAggregation(
                match(criteria),
                unwind("ue"),
                match(where("ue.eId").in(eIds)
                       .and("ue.revoked").ne(Boolean.TRUE)),
                group(fields)
                .addToSet("ue").as("ue"),
                project(fields));
```

Comment: Please share the error log and the domain class as well

Comment: Yes share the code for the model class where you changed the @Id annotation.

Comment: Added the error and the model classes